# How to close `Android Auto` notification

Tags: notifications, charging, android-auto

I plugged my phone into the USB on my rental car so that it would stay charged while I used the phone for navigation -- but it didn't stay charged.

Now I have a notification that I can't get rid of:

```
Google Play services -> Android Auto -> Connected to your car
```

**How do I get rid of this notification?**

*Bonus question: Did `Android Auto` prevent my phone from charging?*

Comment: By the way, the car is off and the phone is not in the car -- but I still can't get rid of the notification.

Comment: Tapping the notification has no effect, which makes me want to tap progressively aggressively.

Comment: Is the device rooted? Fairly easy to do it with NotifyClean Xposed module.

Comment: @Firelord: No, the device is not rooted.

Comment: The notification went away the next day -- maybe after I got in the car again.

Comment: Try this procedure and tell me if it works !
https://support.google.com/androidauto/thread/4024751?msgid=16938659